# Inconsistent readings between oscilloscopes

Tags: electromagnetism, oscilloscope

I have a circuit that pulses a high frequency EM field at a rate of 2Hz.  I'm trying to see the accuracy and precision of the circuit, but I see very different readings on two oscilloscopes I'm using:

Here's the one that I think looks "better" or more like what I expect:
[image: Even height pulses both positive and negative and regular]

And here's the one that I think looks worse:
[image: Pulses not even positive and negative and pulse height is not consistent]

The second oscilloscope is cheaper than the first, but I didn't think it would be that far off.  Additionally when I zoom in on the timescale, say to about 10ms per grid, the pulses are even in height, it's only when I zoom out that it gets worse.

Is there anything that could be causing this that I'm missing?  I've checked through every setting I could find on the second scope and even tried to run its self calibration program.  I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Dave on the EEVBlog recently made a video showing what can go wrong if you zoom in/out. This might apply to your situation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4twnd-YQQ4  The brands of these scopes and their price should indeed be completely irrelevant, it has more to do with **how you use it** than anything else. Especially with these digital (sampling) scopes it is easy to get a **completely wrong** trace on the screen.

Comment: The Tek 1052B only has 2.5k horz data points, so it will miss fast signals at slow timescales. The Instek apparently has more data points so it does a better job in this case. But, as Bimpelrekkie says, any scope will appear to misbehave if you use it wrong.

Comment: Looks like the probe impedance has changed. A low impedance probe input connected to a high impedance source will have the effect of squashing everything vertically. Make sure the probes themselves, and the setting in the scopes is the same (not AC couple 50ohm)

Comment: What is the ADC sample rate?

Comment: Remember your input pulse rise time and width must be > 2x sample interval if you want to capture it and 2^n faster for 2^-n resolution is another way of saying Shannon-Hartley Theorem.. Edge mode has memory

Comment: That video was super helpful with understanding how sampling and the memory works, figured out my issue because of it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual for the 'scope first image shows that you have chosen **peak hold mode** when acquiring samples for display on the screen:
[image: peak hold mode Instek]

This mode catches a short peak that might be otherwise lost *between sample times*. The disadvantage of this mode is that the display may be noisier, showing every little noise peak.

The second oscilloscope uses **Normal mode**, and those short peaks are sometimes lost and not displayed. However, the display has less noise.

Comment: Also, the GW Instek has at least 10x the sample memory of the Tektronix (25k vs. 2.5k points).

Comment: I tried changing to peak hold on both, and they still displayed the same, I think it was more of the sample memory that was pointed out.

Comment: @DaveTweed Tek suggests that their 'scope *always* over-samples at least 10x. Don't know if Instek does that. In any case, the **Normal, Peak-hold, Average** display modes can give considerably different views of the same input wave. Apparently switching modes didn't help, as nrichman kindly pointed out.